# Specify which ViewResolver to use per Controller?

Tags: java, spring, freemarker

I have a freemarker viewresolver in my spring application:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.freemarker.FreeMarkerViewResolver">
```

In my controller methods i can return the name of my freemarker template:

```
return "timeline";
```

Works without any problems.

Now i've created a new template language and i want a few controllers to use this custom template language. So i created a CustomViewResolver.

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.CustomViewResolver">
```

Now i have 2 view resolvers, a freemarker one and my custom one.

How can i specify which ViewResolver should be used by which controller?

Cause my backend will use freemarker and my frontend the custom one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something along the lines of the following example:

**Folder and file structure**

```
webapp
   WEB-INF
       dispatcher-servlet.xml
       jsp
         bar
           bar-baz.jsp
         foo
           foo-fro.jsp
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/bar/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  <property name="viewNames" value="bar-*"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/foo/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
  <property name="viewNames" value="foo-*"/>
</bean>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/bar")
public String bar() { return "bar-baz"; }

@RequestMapping(value="/foo")
public String foo() { return "foo-fro"; }
```

You will be taking advantage of the view name pattern-matching offered by the framework.  If you run into problems, you can try setting an additional `order` property for the view resolvers to control the order in which the resolvers should attempt to locate views for a request.  You would put your custom view resolver at the top (lowest order) and try others if the custom resolver fails.