# Using a class level RequestMapping Annotation to reduce URL length

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, web-applications

If it's possible to reduce the length of a URL in a return sentence of a controller, if i use a class level RequestMapping annotation?

I understand that if you use this code in your controoler class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/ShoppingCarCRUD/")
public class ShoppingCRUD {

    @RequestMapping(value = "add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addShop(Model model) {
        logger.info("LOG INFO ");

        return "/ShoppingCarCRUD/add";
    }
```

you dont have to repeat `/ShoppingCarCRUD/` in `value = "add"` so you can just put `add`, but you need to put `/ShoppingCarCRUD/add` in the return statement `return "/ShoppingCarCRUD/add";`is there a way to short this URL in the return statement the same way that is reduced in the `value` statement

Answer (score 0):

When you return a String from a method annotated with @RequestMapping, you normally return the view name, not the url.

You can configure prefix and suffix of the view resolver in your spring configuration to simplify view names you return.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25379107/2991106) for a suggestion on how to use separate viewresolvers for different controllers

Comment: i read the answer, but since i have 12 modules does that means that i would have to create twelve 12 resolvers??? is there any type of benefits at least in memory management or something, that would bring to my web app if i create twelve 12 resolvers? because i wouldn't care puting the extra long name in my controller if i decide to use 1 resolver but instead of creating 12 twelve resolvers and making my web app more slow, but i dont know i am new using spring, if there any type of benefits creating alot of resolvers??

Comment: There aren't any benefits of using more resolvers that I know of. I would suggest sticking with the long return strings and one resolver. As far as I know that is the usual way of doing things too

Comment: alright if there are no benefits besides having a short URL, are there any drawbacks if use 12 view resolvers??

Comment: In my opinion, I would see it as a drawback to need to maintain 12 resolvers. And hiding part of the path to the view (it is not a URL) in another class makes it harder to locate the view in the future.